# What is Collector's Quality?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Recently TF2 had an update and it added chemistry sets which give you a collector's item when completed.

What's the point of the collector's quality, is it just for people who like to collect things, or is there a special attribute to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It increases the value of that item by placing a cool label on it, other than that, there is no special attribute.

[image: Collector original]

Image grabbed from the [TF Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Collector)

Answer (score 2):

To add on (hopefully not too late), it takes about 200 of that same unique item in order to create a collector's weapon, using the Chemistry set. There are also collector's hats and even collector's festive weapons. If your into any type of trading, it makes these items quite valuable.